# Data Science Groups on Linked In

Tags: social-network-analysis, career

I am interested in joining some Data Science Groups on Linked In.  The relevant list is long.  I don't think it is to my advantage to join all, but I am not sure how to evaluate the individual group's potential to elevate my career.

Is there some clear criteria for which I can evaluate potential groups?

Comment: You'll do more to build your brand by writing blog posts and on sites like this and Quora.

Answer (score 1):

You are limited to
[50 groups](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-max-number-of-groups-on-LinkedIn-allowed).

KDNuggets used number of members, growth rate, number of conversations and member engagment in their 
[analysis of data science groups](http://www.kdnuggets.com/2016/10/top-linkedin-groups-analytics-big-data-mining-data-science.html).

Comment: I like the analysis, but your answer does not address the questions one should ask to take advantage of the analyses.  I hope you don't mind if I combine your answer with mine

Answer (score 0):

I found [this article](http://www.forbes.com/sites/williamarruda/2015/09/30/the-best-way-to-get-started-with-linkedin-groups/#61bf120356a4) at Forbes.com.  It does answer my question directly. In summary it says:

Define what it is that you are looking for from the group: connections, information, exposure.  To do this you need to know who is your authentic self.  Put another way, what is your **Brand**.

Be discriminant about the groups you join.  Only join those that further the goals you have defined.  Research the potential groups to find out if they are in line with your goals.  Join and try the groups found with your research efforts.

KDNuggets used number of members, growth rate, number of conversations and member engagement in their [analysis of data science groups](http://www.kdnuggets.com/2016/10/top-linkedin-groups-analytics-big-data-mining-data-science.html).  This analysis can be used to answer if the specified groups are inline with your goals.

The article goes on to give advice about etiquette once joined, but that is beyond the scope of my question.